# Compare two schemas using toad and Redgate?

Tags: oracle, toad, redgate

How do I compare two Oracle schemas (DEV vs Pre-prod) using Redgate, Toad and create a definition file (.def/.onp)?

Answer (score 1):

RedGate has "[Schema Compare for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/)" tool. Take a look at short video - you will get an idea.

As a source and target you can use live connection to database, snapshot or directory with scripts generated by "Source Control forr Oracle" (which is quite useful too).
Snapshots are very handy if you don't have direct connection to Prod databases, e.g. You can just ask Prod team to generate snapshot and then use it to compare with non-Prod databases.
As a result of comparison you'll get the list of different objects, you can filter them by types and then generate deployment script for target database (right side). Then you can save it or execute immediately.
I'm using command line tools to automate this.
So, just take some time and play with the tools during evaluation period.
You might see some unsupported objects to compare, etc. but the world is not ideal ;-)

I cannot comment about TOAD - don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Toad menu database
Database -> Compare -> Schemas

You must be connected to both instances.